# FFMPEG API - Retrieve device camera information

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, webcam

I need to get the compatible framerate/resolution of the available cameras. How can this be done with the ffmpeg library? I've tried using the functions of `avdevice` but all of them seem to retrieve an error. I am not able to get a list of the available devices as well.

This is being done on a mac using avfoundation (and it will later be ported to windows with dshow).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: unfortunately the "get names" and "get framerate" APIs probably haven't been "fleshed out" for those input devices.  For dshow you can parse the output to "ffmpeg -f dshow -list_devices true -i x" but that's about as good as it gets currently.  Possibly avfoundation has a similar option [?]

Comment: But that would mean running ffmpeg from my program, which the user would have to install along with the app, right? It would work but it's a bit cumbersome I think.

Comment: you could enumerate them "yourself"as it were https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/DirectShow#Howtoprogrammaticallyenumeratedevices

Comment: Hm, that could work. So I would just process what is printed to the terminal. Unfortunately, avfoundation does not support the list_options that dshow supports. So I can not get that information on a mac. I guess the only solution would be to use avfoundation directly?

Comment: Also, that function prints the information to the console. How can I retrieve that so that I can process it?

Answer (score 1):

Try running

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="Integrated Camera"
```

replacing 'dshow' and "Integrated Camera" with whatever you have, depending on the platform. As above, you can get the name of the video device with

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_devices true -i x
```

You can then pipe the resulting output to a file using the > operator, or to a further command-line tool for processing with the | operator. For example,

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="Integrated Camera" > test.txt
```

or

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -list_options true -i video="Integrated Camera" | grep 'pixel_format'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. :) This is an old question I made a few years ago but at the time I was not looking for a command line solution but one with code, using their API, which seemed it wasn't implemented yet.

Comment: Ok, I just bumped into the same problem, and got it solved (apparently with the updated version ;)

Comment: That's good to know. :) Can you add to your answer that it is now possible with the API as well? That way I can accept the answer :)

Comment: Would be good if @k_ride had posted the solution here so people could see it, rather than just saying got it solved with no further detail.

Comment: Very sorry for bad wording - and the delay - but what I meant was that I had the same need, which I solved with that command-line solution in the answer. I never did do it over the API.